# Odoo view translation issue

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am having a strange issue with odoo translation engine:

[image]

The translation works fine for all the fields, but not for the view:
all the translated strings are field labels, but "string" attributes for view.xml tags remain untranslated.

view.xml:

```
                     <page name="public" string="Form 1">
                        <group>
                            <group>
```

....

```
                                    <field name="address_home_id"
                                           context="{'show_address': 1}"
                                           options='{"always_reload": True, "highlight_first_line": True}'
                                           string="Permanent Address"
                                    />
```

However, I do have those strings in both my.po file:

```
#. module: hr_mis
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:hr_mis.view_employee_form
msgid "Form 1"
msgstr "ပုံစံ (၁)"
```

....

```
#. module: hr_mis
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:hr_mis.view_employee_form
msgid "Permanent Address"
msgstr "အမြဲတမ်းနေရပ်လိပ်စာ"
```

and in the database:
[image]

Any idea what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See the post:

[https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/24534][1]

In resume, this Tab/Page string is read from Database, so remove --dev=xml from your runtime config:

> The option -- dev xml is:
>
> xml: read template qweb from xml file directly instead of database.
>   Once a template has been modified in database, it will be not be read
>   from the xml file until the next update/init.
>
> So it means, you are not working with the database for the views. As
>   the translations are stored in the database, it actually make sense.
>   This option is to be used when you are actually developping on your
>   views, to see the result directly.